# Inquiry Regarding Salesforce Integration License Session Expiry

Tags: integration, profile, session

I am looking to set up a profile using the Salesforce Integration license and would like to establish a session expiration time for this profile.

My question is as follows: Considering that the Salesforce Integration license is for system-to-system integration, does the session expiration time apply to this license as well?

For instance, if the session expiration time is set to two hours, does it mean that if a user with a profile linked to this license from an external system sends data, and if they do not send data within two hours, the session will expire and result in an error when trying to send data?

I look forward to your response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Users who have the Salesforce Integration license automatically get the `Salesforce API Only System Integrations` profile.

If you  edit that profile, and change the Session Settings, then all users (i.e. API-only users assigned to this Profile) will get those session settings

> does the session expiration time apply to this license as well?

Not exactly, it applies to the users that use that license's Profile.  Session expiration is a feature of the Profile (and hence inherited by users of that profile). In this case, the license applies to one-and-only-one profile.

> For instance, if the session expiration time is set to two hours, does it mean that if a user with a profile linked to this license from an external system sends data, and if they do not send data within two hours, the session will expire and result in an error when trying to send data?

The answer is YES and the remote system should have logic to handle this situation if relying on an active session between API calls.  Often, this simply handling expired OAuth tokens but other aps may need to login again to get a new authorization token.

This is no different than before Salesforce introduced the special (5 free, cheap for more) Salesforce Integration licenses.